# How do I set an 8-bit Texture on OpenGl-ES 2.0 for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to use an 8-bit texture (I only need 256 values per pixel in it) on android opengl-es 2.0 and would like to know how I set it with glTexImage2D.

Would GL_ALPHA8 work ?

I didn't find any list of standard supported texture formats that are supported by android (or at least most devices with at least android 2.2 and opengl 2.0). I have no device to test it available right now so I would really like some advice on this.

The reason for this is because I want to use a texture for my fragment shader that takes as little memory as possible and it only needs to hold 256 values.

Answer (score 0):

From the official openGL ES documentation:

*type* argument in `glTexImage2D`:

> Specifies the data type of the texel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1.

If you want to use this function, you have to choose one of them :)
Most likely you search `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` while a byte contains 8 bits :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I choose GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE for the type, but what do I choose for the internalformat and format parameters so that only 1 byte per pixel is being used and not 4 ?

Comment: I would use GL_RGB or GL_LUMINANCE for both parameters, depends on what you are using. Just note that both should have matching constants.

Comment: GL_RGB does need 3 bytes per value, right ? And GL_LUMINANCE doesn't seem to work for me. I tried it with GL_ALPHA though which seems to work. Problem is though I don't know how much video memory it allocates for a pixel: 1 byte, 4 bytes or something entirely different.